# Make all iteration of subreport in detail band come together. Before next detail band is printed

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Please help me I have deadline with the project.

I have `SubReport` in the `detailBand1`, which has `List dataSource` to iterate.

The second `detailBand2` has some static data and it is followed by `detailBand3` which again have a `subreport` with `List dataSource`.

1. I want first all the iteration (depending on number of elements in
   the list.) of `detailBand1` to be printed
2. Then `DetailBand2` printed Once (As it has static text) .
3. Followed by `DetailBand3` with all its elements.

**Example:**

[image: Example]

**Report layout**
[image: Image of jasper report layout]

Comment: Why all these detail bands?, the subreport needs to be repeated or not... from what I see not!!, the repeating is inside the subreport!, try using other bands.. title ecc. and consider groups if you need to controll page break

Comment: @PetterFriberg SubReport need to be repeated and it is getting repeated. But after it is printing once Detail band2 data is printed and after that 2nd iteration of detailBand1 is getting printed. For example in above code if there are 2 location. for 1st location subreport data is printed then contents of detail band2 and then for 2nd location detailBand1 contents are printed. I want first all iteration of detail band1 to be printed together then contents of detailBand2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifing your question is it possibile to do?

> Band1(Record 1)
>
> Band1(Record 2)
>
> Band2 (Record 1)
>
> Band2 (Record 2)

Without changing the datasource **this is not possibile**

hence, the band 2 is actually inside the detail band

```
<detail>
    <band/> //Band 1
    <band/> //Band 2
</detail>
```

so the execution will be

> Band1(Record 1)
>
> Band2(Record 1)
>
> Band1 (Record 2)
>
> Band2 (Record 2)

If you absolutly do not want to re-consider your report structure, this could be achived duplicating data in your datasource, setting property on duplicated data to understand if to write in `band1` or in `band2` and then using the `Print When Condition` on the band.

In this case your datasource becomes:

- Record 1 (property:band 1)
- Record 2 (property:band 1)
- Record 1 (property:band 2)
- Record 2 (property:band 2)

`band1` has `Print When Condition: property=band 1`

`band2` has `Print When Condition property=band 2`

However, I suggest you re-consider your report and data structure using group bands and subreports to achive desired result.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Am new to these reports can u share some example for using group bands and subreports. i can change the structure of the reports.Thanks

Comment: There are alot of example on the web (use your favorite search engine), try to figure out what is your main dataset (maybe there is not and can be an JREmptyDataSource(1), all queries done in subreport since they are multiple). Fake group bands (you group on value that is always same so you get only one group), is effective to control page break, Hence you can set min-height properties ecc. If you worked out something that can work and still have problem post a new question.... remember including relevant code and a clear problem description.

Comment: @Abhinav Sharma consider accepting the answer, to close this question